# success ajax: if is 200 status code run function else another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why doesn't work... i use `$.ajax` for run file.php and pass it (`POST`) a value of input
This file.php works but my function ajax doesn't work:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file.php',
            data: { email: $('#andressemail').val() },
            success: function(data,status){
                if(status === '200'){
                    newmessage();
                }
                else{
                    erroremessage();
                }
            }
        });

       funtion newmessage(){
        alert('ok');
       }

       funtion erroremessage(){
        alert('no');
       }
```

The file.php works fine (it adds an user at my newsletter), but for `$.ajax` doesn't work and status code is not `200`

Why ?

Comment: try this: status == 'success'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following to get status code, use xhr.status for statuscode:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file.php',
        data: { email: $('#andressemail').val() },
        success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            if(xhr.status === '200'){
                newmessage();
            }
            else{
                erroremessage();
            }
        }
    });

   funtion newmessage(){
    alert('ok');
   }

   funtion erroremessage(){
    alert('no');
   }
```

Comment: your code is god but "xhr.status === 200 " (not '200') no ?

Comment: yes...have you alert xhr.status, which value foes it returning on failure?

Comment: make it:  xhr.status === 200

Answer (score 1):

The success function only runs when the HTTP response is already `200`. You need to use error function as well which fires when the HTTP response is not finished correctly. Change your code to look like:

```
function newmessage(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  alert('ok');
}

function erroremessage(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  alert('no');
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'file.php',
  data: { email: $('#andressemail').val() },
  success: newmessage,
  error: erroremessage
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with `$.ajax` is this:

```
var _ajax = function(url, data, type){
    return $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
    });
}

var data = { email: $('#andressemail').val() };

_ajax('file.php', data, 'POST')
    .success(function(res, statusTitle, xhr){
        // res: response from server
        // statusTitle = 'success', ...
        // xhr: XHR object, for your case, xhr.status will be 200
    });
```

you can use `.error(function(){...})` too, (also `.done`);